# Loading"Gruntfile.js"tasks...ERROR

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

require('time-grunt')(grunt);

var config = {
    app:'app',
    dist:'dist'
}

grunt.initConfig({
    config: config,

    copy: {
        dist_html: {
            src:'<%= config.app %>/index.html',
            dest:'<%= config.dist %>/index.html'
        },
        dist_js: {
            src:'<%= config.app %>/js/index.js',
            dest:'<%= config.dist %>/js/index.js'
        }
    },

    clean: {
        dist: {
            src: '<%= config.dist %>/index.html'
        }
    }
});}}
```

[cmd picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pl0J9.png)
I input “grunt copy”in cmd,but it error.I started to learn grunt soon,How can I solve this problem?I need help,thinks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the task to be able to use it in cmd.

For example:

```
grunt.registerTask(taskName, [description, ] taskFunction)
```

Answer (score 0):

you only have configured what pathes to use you should create a task like so:

```
grunt.task({
 // Do Stuff here
})
```

There is more information on grunt tasks here:
http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task